# Dynamically superscript on dates in a string

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically change "th" and "st" on Dates that appear in a string. For example in a DIV there is 
    `<div class="date">Thursday, September 14th 2017</div>` 
I want to query to find "th" and superscript it. I found the below code that works but it also superscripts characters in the day and month as well. I'm not sure how target only the characters "th" that are next to each other.

```
$('.date').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.replace(/[th]/g, '<sup>$&</sup>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTfxC/133/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to support the four different ordinals: **st**, **nd**, **rd**, **th**

You probably don't want lowercase word parts of the date to get superscripted (e.g. mo**nd**ay, **th**ursday), and the date could be at the end of a string or followed by a punctuation mark, etc.

Match any of the four ordinals when they follow a digit and are followed by any non-alphanumeric character or by the end of the string:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("li").each(function() {
      var original = $(this).text();
      $(this).html(original.replace(/(\d)(st|nd|rd|th)(\W|$)/g, "$1<sup>$2</sup>$3"));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Monday, May 1st</li>
  <li>Monday, May 1st!</li>
  <li>Monday, May 1st.</li>
  <li>Monday, May 1st&nbsp;</li>
  <li>Monday, May 1st 2017</li>
  <li>Monday, May 1st 2017 until Tuesday, May 2nd 2017</li>
  <li>Tuesday, May 2nd 2017</li>
  <li>Wednesday, May 3rd 2017</li>
  <li>Thursday, May 4th 2017</li>
  <li>thursday, May 4th 2017</li>
</ul>

<button>Run Demo</button>
```

**TL;DR** `replace(/(\d)(st|nd|rd|th)(\W|$)/g, "$1<sup>$2</sup>$3")`

Comment: Great explanation and answer, works exactly as I need. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Note that I just updated my answer, the previous one wouldn't have worked if the date was at the end of a sentence (i.e. followed by punctuation).

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are trying is having **[ ]** around th, which means either t or h, that's why you are getting wrong result. Just change below line in your code :

`return this.nodeValue.replace(/th/g, '<sup>$&</sup>');`

Answer (score 0):

Repalce your code with:

```
$('.date').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
    return this.nodeValue.replace(/(\d)(st|nd|rd|th)(\W|$)/g, "$1<sup>$2</sup>$3");
});
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvay6ctz/1/)